# Facing this error message : "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames"

Tags: support, feature-request, bug

```
"For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames"
```

Whenever I open stackExchange site I come across this message everytime. It is not with this laptop, it is same error with my windows phone and office MAC book.

What should I do ? How do I get rid of this.?[image]